# Blazor Wasm PWA not updating

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, progressive-web-apps, webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM PWA application that I have published on a hosting service on IIS. The problem that I have encountered is that sometimes the application doesn't update in the visitor's browser. I.e. they see an older version of the application.

I know that the application cache should be updated by the service worker, so it could be that you need to visit the website once, and then close the browser and visit it again to get the updated version. However, sometimes it looks like the cache just gets messed up and no matter what, the application will not update. The only solution I've found is to press F12, go to the Application tab and delete everything from there -> this will force the latest version of the application to be downloaded again.

Does anyone know what is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue with latest version of .net 6 and blazor.

Answer (score 8):

Declare a `js` file for registration in the navigator.serviceWorker object.

```
 /**
  * Register Service Worker
  */
 navigator.serviceWorker
     .register('/***.js', { scope: '/' })
     .then(() => {
         console.log('Service Worker Registered');
     });
```

This js file can contain a cache version like below.

```
 const CACHE_VERSION = 1.0.
```

Update cache_version when the code changes to force the cache to refresh. Anytime the register *.js file changes, the browser updates the service worker to its new version.

```
 const CACHE_VERSION = 1.1;
```

Comment: Do I need to check this variable to update? Could you improve your answer ?

Comment: I don't have any navigator.serviceWorker object in my project. Everytime i compile i have to clear the cache in the browser to reflect he modifications in the pages. I would like to automate this, as i think i will encounter the same problem upon deploy. Could you explain better where do i put that code? Please

Comment: @Ricardo Araújo In the app's [wwwroot/index.html](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/ComponentsWebAssembly-CSharp/Client/wwwroot/index.html) file, more details about [Build Progressive Web Applications with ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @Mårshåll This is late but this could help others: According to [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#background-updates-1), just changing the number _should_ bring the new version:
`The files are compared byte-for-byte with the existing installed service worker. If the server returns changed content for either of these files, the service worker attempts to install a new version of itself.`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intended to complement Michael Wong's answer:

Blazor automatically updates to the newer version (at least in .NET 5, possibly earlier too).
This happens when the application is first closed and restarted in ALL browser tabs including the installed app (which is another browser tab).

The following article helped me a lot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#installation-and-app-manifest-1

Also helpful:
https://www.eugenechiang.com/2021/05/22/forcing-reload-of-blazor-client-after-publishing-changes/

Comment: So are you saying this refresh behaviour should be build into blazor by default?

Comment: @Zapnologica It's built into browsers in general, loading the new service worker after all tabs are closed.